# button_to with GET method option in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following button, which I overwrited to generate a GET request:

```
= button_to "Tutor", {:controller => "appointments", :action => "new",
    :listing_id => @listing.id} , :method => :get
```

However, I still get a POST request with extra params :method:

```
  Processing by AppointmentsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"AWkL", "listing_id"=>"2", "method"=>"get"}
```

I my routes file, I have:

```
 resources :appointments
```

What did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Buttons aren't supposed to be sending `GET` requests.

You should use a `link_to` instead. If you want it to look like a button, apply some CSS. Here's a good article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/18/designing-css-buttons-techniques-and-resources/

Comment: What about Search buttons?  They often use `GET` requests.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. When someone asks, "How do I do X?" it's changing the topic to answer with, "You shouldn't do X, but Y instead."

Comment: @LukeLaupheimer: sometimes (quite often, in fact), that IS a valid answer. Maybe not in this case.

Comment: Seriously annoyed with these "opinionated" answers. I know that this is an ancient question but I'm just getting on the rails train. I want off.

In my case I'm adding an oauth "connect with..." button. It makes sense to use the GET method because that's how the request is sent. Yeah, I could go out of my way to add css and use link_to, but why should I have to do all the extra work because of someone else's opinion? That's just asinine.

Comment: @VictorUde: you're gonna style it anyway, so I don't see much difference.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I'm not though... I'm writing something bare bones as a proof. Not the typical use case I imagine. It's a pain that both link_to and button_to simply drop query params without indication. I ended up just using form_tag because it works predictably and there's no "magic" involved.

Comment: The opinion is valid, and has it's place, however if you simply want to know "how to do it" check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011565/4880924

Answer (score 50):

Just use **method**: and **:get**

```
button_to "New User", new_user_path, method: :get
```

Comment: That's what he uses, no?

Comment: In case you have some html options, remember to wrap everything in a hash: `button_to "New User", new_user_path, {method: 'get', class: "some-class"}`

Comment: Or if you need to use a path hash, make sure to separate out the `method` from it: `button_to "Frob User", {action: :frob, id: user.id}, method: :get`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [UJS driver code](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js):

[`a\[data-method\]`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L53) is the selector used here:

So the following should work (couldn't really test it):

```
button_to "Tutor", {...}, :html => { "data-method" => "get" }
```

Comment: Thanks Tigraine. Your solution doesn't work for me. I suspect that there might be conflict between Prototype (which I removed) with jQuery that prevents me from forcing a get method.

Comment: Ah sorry.. I just looked at the UJS code and thought this should work.. At least if you use a `<a>` tag it should

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a link with button tag.

`link_to(new_appointments_path(listing.id)) { button_tag("My button", class: 'my-btn-class') }`