# RoR: button click action call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this has been asked in 100's of pages and I tried a lot to get it working. I do not know where I am missing out:

controller (logins)

```ruby
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def create

  end
  def buttons

  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
LoginApp::Application.routes.draw do

match "logins/index" => "logins#index", :as => :index , :via => :get

match "logins/create" => "logins#create", :as => :create ,:via => :get

match "buttons" => "logins#buttons", :via => :get
#get "logins/buttons" => "logins#buttons"
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= button_to   'Submit', { :action => "buttons", :controller => "logins"} %>
```

The buttons.html.erb page is created in the views directory.

When I click "Submit" Button, I get:

```
No route matches [POST] "/logins/index"
```

I tried changing the routes.rb, various form in index.htm.erb for buttons but not able to get it working. Have I overlooked anything?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of the other answers not working, here is what I propose:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :logins, only: [:index, :create] do
    collection do
        get :buttons
    end
end

#view
<%= link_to "Submit", logins_buttons_path # -> whatever the path helper is %>
```

I have used [`link_to`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684467/button-to-with-get-method-option-in-rails) because this answer recommends `button_to` for `POST` requests. This should work for you, but it's non-conventional, so you'll be best describing how you want it it work

---

**Update**

I am glad this worked for you

Several things which probably contributed to its functionality:

1. Conventional routes
2. Using `link_to`

When using [`routing` in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), it's basically middleware which defines how your app will "catch" incoming requests. When you browse to `domain.com/route`, Rails takes the `/route` & the `HTTP verb` part of the URL & loads the corresponding `controller / action` to help it load up.

When defining your routes, you therefore need to be extremely careful about which `routes` you define, and how you define them. The best way is to use Rails conventions (which essentially means using inbuilt helpers) such as [`resources :controller`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

--

We also used the `link_to` in place of [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

`button_to` creates a small form on your page, which then sends a request to your assigned route. This form is typically `POST`, but can be assigned `GET`. In light of your new comment, you'll probably want to read up on the [`button_to` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) to get it formatted correctly

Comment: thanks rick.the trick has worked for me..but why the above mentioned solutions are not working..also can you provide the link for further explaination of the above solution..thanks again..

Comment: also, I found that button is the only problem. When I used link_to in the html.erb and match in routes.rb..it was working fine..I am pretty confused about the cause..also how can I use the button as link seems pretty off for the login page..thanks again everyone.

Comment: Updated for you - you may wish to upvote & accept the answer if it help resolve your issue

Comment: I think I am still getting the hold of submit and routes. Now I tried using form_tag since I do not have to populate any model. My index.html.erb looks like:   <%= form_tag(controller: "logins", method: "post") do %>
  <p><%= link_to('Register', {:action => 'create'}) %> 
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :controller => "logins", :action =>"clicked", :method => "post" %></p>  routes.rb looks like resources :logins do  post :clicked, on: :collection end. whenever I am hitting the submit button, the browser link says method=get why?, also It stays on the index.html.erb and not going to clicked.html.erb.

Answer (score 3):

The method of button_to is post by default.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

> :method - Symbol of HTTP verb. Supported verbs are :post, :get,
>   :delete, :patch, and :put. By default it will be :post.

Change the code in index.html.erb :

```
<%= button_to   'Submit', { :action => "buttons", :controller => "logins"},  method: :get %>
```

Comment: you dont want to submit a login form via get method :)

Comment: According to the routes.rb he wants: 
match "buttons" => "logins#buttons", :via => :get

Comment: yeah but it would be plain wrong to send the username/password in URL. the correct way to fix this would be to add post as well in routes.

Answer (score 0):

You have only get method defined in your routes.rb. That is why the error says no route matches for "POST" method. Add post method as well.

```
match "logins/index" => "logins#index", :as => :index , :via => [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Thanks emailleni..Now it doesnot show the error but the page is getting redirected back to index page..it is not hitting the buttons action..it is staying on index page..

Comment: check your routes again. In your view, the action is buttons, but the earlier error was for index action. Check your code again.

Comment: It does not seem to be working for me..                               match "logins/buttons" => "logins#buttons", :as => :buttons, :via =>:post. The index page is getting refreshed all the time. I also tried with [:get, :post] in the above line (trying everything)..I am still not getting where I am missing out. Stuck on this basic for so long..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old post....

This can be done in rails 4 as :

```
<%= button_to   'Submit', prefix_path,  method: :get %>
```

prefix_path can be seen when you press rake routes and add '_path' at the end and replace in place of prefix_path